# Check if notification exists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, notifications

Chrome browser.

The script is executed every time the page is refreshed.

Is it possible to verify the existence of a notification so as not to duplicate it.

```js
if ($('.snippet__title').length) {
  var titles = document.querySelectorAll('.snippet__title')
  titles.forEach((title) => {
    if (title.textContent.includes('searchString')) {
      var msg = title.textContent.trim()
      var notification = new Notification('Element found', {
        body: msg,
        dir: 'auto',
        icon: 'icon.jpg'
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: from Mozilla docs " it's possible to modify the pending notifications queue, replacing single or multiple pending notifications with a new one." will this work for you?

Comment: Set a value in localStorage

Comment: Why do you use, I presume, jQuery only (at all) for the `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks *mplungjan*. So I thought to do it, but I thought there are still some solutions.

**Working solution using localStorage**

```
    var NotifyShowed = localStorage.getItem('NotifyShowed')

    if (!NotifyShowed) {
        if ($('.snippet__title').length) {
          var titles = document.querySelectorAll('.snippet__title')
          titles.forEach((title) => {
            if (title.textContent.includes('searchString')) {
              var msg = title.textContent.trim()
              var notification = new Notification('Element found', {
                body: msg,
                dir: 'auto',
                icon: 'icon.jpg'
              });
              localStorage.setItem('NotifyShowed', true);
            }
          })
        }
    }
```